# Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression

Tags: javascript

I have the following errors 5 times:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left - hand side expression in
>   postfix operation

Do you guys sees why ? Appreciate your help !

```
toQueryParams: function (string, separator) {
  var match = _(string).strip().match(/([^?#]*)(#.*)?$/);
  if (!match) return {};
  return _(match[1].split(separator || '&')).reduce(function (hash, pair) {
    if ((pair = pair.split('='))[0]) {
      var key = decodeURIComponent(pair.shift()),
        value = pair.length > 1 ? pair.join('=') : pair[0];
      if (value != undefined) value = decodeURIComponent(value);
      if (key in hash) {
        if (!_.isArray(hash[key])) hash[key] = [hash[key]];
        hash[key].push(value);
      }
      // Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left - hand side expression in postfix operation
      // Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left - hand side expression in postfix operation
      // Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left - hand side expression in postfix operation
      // Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left - hand side expression in postfix operation
      // Uncaught ReferenceError: Invalid left - hand side expression in postfix operation
      else hash[key] = value;
    }
    return hash;
  }, {});
},
```

Comment: Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo.

Comment: well it's part of a very large JS file. I'm gonna miss dependencies... I'll see what I can do

Comment: here it is http://jsfiddle.net/YcN4F/ I've updated the code to try something but does not work in production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what's happening. It was not this code but when trying to minify underscore.js using an old version of JSMin...

I'll move to uglyfier now.